# Can a trait like selfishness improve

Tags: personality

Can a trait like selfishness improve with therapy or other methods. Or is it fixed and can not be changed whatever you do.

This article claims that it can be done, but I need more solid reasearch data :

https://www.vice.com/en_au/article/9kkeyd/can-a-psychologist-cure-my-worst-character-trait-unstoppable-selfishness